# Menus is not showing in Another Activity in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-menu

when i start a new Activity on menu item click in second activity menu bar is not showing.My Second Ativity.java:-

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if(id == R.id.action_search){
        speak();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Search action is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void speak(){
    Intent intent  = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,getClass().getPackage().getName());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);
}}
```

And Here My search_menu.xml is here:-

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

here my activity_search.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/myEditText"
    android:hint="@string/search"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar >
</LinearLayout>
```

I am new in android developing please help me.

Comment: Try to remove the `EditText` from your `Toolbar` in xml

Comment: If i remove EditText than how can i show searchview toolbar

Comment: Add `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"` in your search menu item. And change `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` to  `app:showAsAction="always"` to be always visible.

Comment: after removing EditText and adding adding above line in menu xml toolbar is come empty

Comment: If you say i also post my first activity and layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the toolbar as the activity's action bar.

In onCreate(), add this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html for more info.